# inner join select (A,B) on A and B vs where (A,B) in select(A, B) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the best query between theses two ?
They output the same result, expect one is doing the condition inside a `where in` and the other one inside an `inner join`.

```
select uv.* from version v inner join user_version uv ON v.id=uv.version_id
WHERE (v.number, v.master_id) IN (
select max(v.number) as number, v.master_id 
  from version v inner join user_version uv ON v.id=uv.version_id group by v.master_id);
```

and

```
 select * from user_version uv 
   inner join version v on v.id=uv.version_id and v.number
   inner join (
      select uv2.user_id, max(v2.number) maxNumber, v2.master_id master_id, v2.id version_id from version v2 
         inner join user_version uv2 on v2.id=uv2.version_id group by v2.master_id ) test
   on test.master_id=v.master_id and test.maxNumber=v.number ;
```

I've created a sqlfiddle with an example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76001/62
(The idea is to get the biggest version of a "master" entity linked to a given user)

If you have other ideas (I'm using mysql, so I can't use windows function)

Thanks

Comment: In general, 'uncorrelated subquery' solutions like the second one tend to be faster than their alternatives. Your query is a bit more complex, but I think the principle holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not too easy to answer this question. You should know one important thing: MySQL treats `IN (<static values list>)` and `IN (<subquery>)` as [different queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html). First one is equal to *range comparison* (like `.. OR = .. OR =`) while second is equal to `= ANY ()` - and it's not the same. So, to say short: using `IN` with subquery will cause query with `ANY()` and MySQL will not use index for that even if subquery is independent and returns *static list of values*. Sad, but true. MySQL can't predict that and so index will not be used even if it's obvious. If you'll use `JOIN` (i.e. rewrite your `IN (<subquery>)`) - then MySQL will use index for `JOIN` condition, if it's possible.

Now, the second case may be about `JOIN` and `IN` when using partitions. If you'll use `JOIN` - then, sadly - but MySQL also is not able to predict partitions for `JOIN` in common case - and it will use entire set of partitions for it. Replacing `JOIN` to `IN (<static list>)` will change `EXPLAIN PARTITION` picture: MySQL will use only those partitions, which are needed for selecting values from range, specified within `IN` clause. But, again, this will not work with `IN (<subquery>)`.

As a conclusion - it's sad, when we're saying about how MySQL is handling `IN` subqueries - and in common case it can't be replaced with `JOIN` safely (that's about partitioning case). So, common solution will be: *separate subquery from main query on application level*. If we're saying about independent subquery, returning static values list, that's the best suggestion - then you can substitute that values list as `IN(<static list>)` and gain benefits: MySQL will use index for it, and, if we're saying about partitions, only actually needed from them will be used.

Comment: are you saying that the first request won't use index on master_id/number, and for the second one the sub-select will return all the result matching the select for each line, without a filter on the test.master_id=v.master_id condition ? (the PARTITION idea isn't really clear for me in this case)

Comment: First one will not use index for `IN` subquery